# Convert string of values into an object in Java

Tags: java, gson

I have a string like `"name=lokesh,age=25"`. I want to retrieve those values by property name.

I tried converting it to a `JsonObject` by using Google Gson. But it threw an error because it is not valid `JsonObject`.

Is there way to retrieve those values by each property like `Obj.get("name")` etc

Comment: Friend, you haven't given us an *answerable* question!  It does us no good at all for you to simply tell us that you "tried converting" this-or-that.  And then, when you talk about retrieving "those values" ...?!  We have nothing to go on!  Therefore:  please re-formulate your question, including specific excerpts of your source-code.  **Get *specific.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may convert the String into a Map:

```
String str = "name=lokesh,age=25";
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
for(String keyValueStr: str.split(",")){
     String[] keyValue = keyValueStr.split("=");
     map.put(keyValue[0],keyValue[1]);
 }
```

Then, you are free to access the values by keys

```
String name = map.get("name");
```

> Or using guava's Splitter (I wouldn't add the dependency just for that):

```
String str = "name=lokesh,age=25";
Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(str);
```

With the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```